# Reclassify function in ArcMap 10.5 does not correctly reclassify values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, reclassify

I reclassified a raster layer containing three classes (0-0.05, color = white; 0.05-0.5, color = dark salmon; and 0.5-1, color = red)

[image: original]

to a raster layer where theses ranges were replaced with 0 (color = brown), 1 (color = purple) or 2 (color = blue), respectively. While the reclassify function correctly converted values for most raster cells, it does not do so for one (there is a class 2 cell missing in the top left).

[image: reclassified]

I have 9 such raster files that I reclassified. For some, the reclassify function correctly reclassifies all cells, but for others it does not. Despite that the steps to reclassify are the same for all. Any ideas what causes this discrepancy, or what am I overlooking?

Comment: Try running zonal statistics as table min  max to see what went wrong.  Precision settings can be an issue

Comment: I am having this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Before I used the reclassify function within ArcMap, I changed the symbology from continuous to discrete, specifying three classes. I set the upper limit manually to 1, but the exact maximum value was sometimes slightly more than 1 e.g., 1.000004826. When I reclassified with keeping the upper limit the same, all values properly reclassify.